# Magento 2 : Editor designer background color

Tags: magento2, editor

where can I change the colour of the editor "Designer"? I think the color is #F3F4F6, but where can I change the color or where is the file where I can change it?

I need help, thank you guys

Im using Magento Ver.-2.3.2

Comment: Can you specify requirement in some more detail or possible with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I mean this background colour, where I added some crosses